# Android M Device loses authorization repeatedly

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I'm running the Android M developer preview on a Nexus 5 and I keep running into an issue where my device loses its USB authorization over...and over...and over...and it's making it really difficult to continue testing.

Has anyone experienced this??

I've tried plugging into different ports (USB2.0 and 3.0) I've killed the ADB process through the task manager and the server by way of adb kill-server adb start-server, and toggling USB debugging on and off but it's still happening.

Even if it is a USB issue, my computers RSA fingerprint shouldn't be changing...

It seems to be only after being plugged in for a little while ~10 minutes.

Comment: are you using `platform-tools` revision `23.0.0 rc1`?

Comment: That was it...I hadn't updated my ANDROID_HOME variable to point to the latest platform-tools. Provide an answer and I'll give you the points.

Comment: This is happening to be with Lollipop also, I wonder if my ANDROID_HOME is incorrect. WIll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android M you need to use the latest version of `platform-tools` - revision `23.0.0 rc1`